# Mostrar texto que fica escondido ao mudar de linha

Tags: css

Tenho o problema com o css do meu checkbox.

Código do checkbox:

```css
.funkyradio div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.funkyradio label {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty {
  display: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 3.25em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
  color: #888;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #C2C2C2;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  color: #777;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:focus ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}

.funkyradio-success input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 height: 0;
}

.form_wrapper .input_field, .form_wrapper .textarea_field {
 position:relative;
}
.form_wrapper .input_field > span, .form_wrapper .textarea_field > span {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 color:#333;
 height:100%;
 border-right:1px solid #ccc;
 text-align:center;
 width:30px;
}
.form_wrapper .textarea_field > span {
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 max-height:35px;
}
.form_wrapper .input_field > span > i, .form_wrapper .textarea_field > span > i {
 padding-top:12px;
}

.col_half {
 width:40%;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="col_half" style="float: left">
<label style="font-size:16px">Humor/Comportamento/Personalidade</label>
<div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa"></i></span>
<div class="funkyradio">
<div class="funkyradio-success">
<input type="checkbox" name="Euforia" id="Euforia1" Value="Sim" ' . ( ($row["Euforia"]=='Sim') ? 'checked' : '' ) .' readonly="true">
<label for="Euforia1">Sente Euforia (Alegria Patológica Desproporcional à Circunstância)</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Mas ao visualizar esconde uma parte do texto, uma vez que muda de linha.

Como posso resolver este problema, nos casos que mudam de linha?

Comment: Seja mais específico, qual o restado você está esperando ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque a propriedade `text-indent: 3.25em;` por `padding-left: 3.25em;` na label.

O `text-indent` só vai indentar a primeira linha do texto, ou seja, se houver quebra de linha, da segunda linha em diante do texto não sofrerá indentação.

> Talvez outros ajustes sejam necessários (no `line-height` do texto e
>   ajustes no checkbox), mas como a dúvida era apenas sobre o texto da
>   label, o `padding-left` já resolve.

**Veja:**

```css
.funkyradio div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.funkyradio label {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty {
  display: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  /*text-indent: 3.25em;*/
  padding-left: 3.25em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
  color: #888;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #C2C2C2;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  color: #777;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:focus ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}

.funkyradio-success input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 visibility: hidden;
 height: 0;
}

.form_wrapper .input_field, .form_wrapper .textarea_field {
 position:relative;
}
.form_wrapper .input_field > span, .form_wrapper .textarea_field > span {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 color:#333;
 height:100%;
 border-right:1px solid #ccc;
 text-align:center;
 width:30px;
}
.form_wrapper .textarea_field > span {
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 max-height:35px;
}
.form_wrapper .input_field > span > i, .form_wrapper .textarea_field > span > i {
 padding-top:12px;
}

.col_half {
 width:40%;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="col_half" style="float: left">
<label style="font-size:16px">Humor/Comportamento/Personalidade</label>
<div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa"></i></span>
<div class="funkyradio">
<div class="funkyradio-success">
<input type="checkbox" name="Euforia" id="Euforia1" Value="Sim" ' . ( ($row["Euforia"]=='Sim') ? 'checked' : '' ) .' readonly="true">
<label for="Euforia1">Sente Euforia (Alegria Patológica Desproporcional à Circunstância)</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Vc colocou bottom:0 no pseudo elemento, por isso ele "estica" até o final do container pai, cobrindo parte do texto que está abaixo quando quebra a  linha.

Uma das forma simples de resolver é tirar o `bottom:0` e colocar um `height` fixo em `PX`, ou `EM` (EMs seria mais indicado)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além disso para centralizar o `✔️` no box, coloque `display: flex` no pseudo elemento e `coloque align-items: center`

Segue o código da imagem acima

```css
.funkyradio div {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.funkyradio label {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #D1D3D4;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty {
  display: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  text-indent: 3.25em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:empty ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:empty ~ label:before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  /* bottom: 0; */
  height: 19px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 2.5em;
  background: #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label {
  color: #888;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:hover:not(:checked) ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #C2C2C2;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label {
  color: #777;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  content: '\2714';
  text-indent: .9em;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.funkyradio input[type="radio"]:focus ~ label:before,
.funkyradio input[type="checkbox"]:focus ~ label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #999;
}

.funkyradio-success input[type="radio"]:checked ~ label:before,
.funkyradio-success input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ label:before {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.form_wrapper .input_field,
.form_wrapper .textarea_field {
  position: relative;
}

.form_wrapper .input_field > span,
.form_wrapper .textarea_field > span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}

.form_wrapper .textarea_field > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-height: 35px;
}

.form_wrapper .input_field > span > i,
.form_wrapper .textarea_field > span > i {
  padding-top: 12px;
}

.col_half {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col_half" style="float: left">
    <label style="font-size:16px">Humor/Comportamento/Personalidade</label>
    <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa"></i></span>
      <div class="funkyradio">
        <div class="funkyradio-success">
          <input type="checkbox" name="Euforia" id="Euforia1" Value="Sim" ' . ( ($row["Euforia"]==' Sim') ? 'checked' : '' ) .' readonly="true">
          <label for="Euforia1">Sente Euforia (Alegria Patológica Desproporcional à Circunstância)</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```